# Parse and Display sheet in google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sites, google-sheets-api

I want to be able to parse a google sheet column for a number and display the entire row using google script and html.

At the moment I can display the entire sheet very easily.

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate();
}

function getData() {
  return SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('0AvF9FEyqXFxAdEplRHp5dGc4Q1E3OXMyV2s4RktiQWc')
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues();
}
```

Index.html

```
<? var data = getData(); ?>
<table border='1px solid black'>
  <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
    <tr>
      <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
        <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
      <? } ?>
    </tr>
  <? } ?>
</table>
```

I have attempted to import the sheet and build an array, then use a for loop for the value I am searching for without success.

```
function rowOf(containingValue, range) { 
  var outRow = null;

  if(range.constructor == Array)
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++)
    {
      if(range[i].constructor == Array && range[i].length > 0)
      {
        if (range[i][0] == containingValue)
        {
          outRow = i+1;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return outRow;
}
```

How can I get a single row output based on a value in a column?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0])
  var col = 1 ; // choose the column you want to check: 0 = col A, 1= col B ...
  var range = sh.getDataRange();
  var values=range.getValues();// data is a 2D array, index0 = col A
  Logger.log(values)

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {     
      if (values[i][j] == "Jeremy") {
        row = values[i];
        Logger.log(row);
        Logger.log(i); // This is your row number
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

In my Spreadsheet :

[image]

My Logs:

[image]

Hope this helps.